# Получение списка LSP

Tags: windows, winapi, winsock

Как получить список установленных на машине LSP?

Если верить [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450110.aspx), то они зарегистрированы в HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\COMM\WS2\LSP но у меня нет ключа COMM. Я думал, что его просто не показывает regedit, но открыть его через RegOpenKeyEx не удается - возвращается:

> ошибка 87 (неверный параметр)

Хотя для любого ключа все прекрасно работает (я менял только путь к ключу). Такие продукты как АВЗ прекрасно показывают эти LSP.. или они их берут откуда-то еще?

Comment: На десктопе или на CE, который описан по ссылке?

Comment: Десктоп, просто похожей статьи для него я не нашел, вот и дал ссылку на СЕ

Answer (score 2):

Используя функцию *WSCEnumProtocols*. Код на основе примера из [Windows SDK](https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/tree/e8fe83b043727e71f5179da11fc6228475e7973c/netds/winsock/lsp):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ws2spi.h>
//https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/blob/e8fe83b043727e71f5179da11fc6228475e7973c/netds/winsock/lsp/install/instlsp.cpp

#pragma comment(lib,"Ws2_32.lib")

typedef enum
{
    LspCatalogBoth = 0,
    LspCatalog32Only,
    LspCatalog64Only
} WINSOCK_CATALOG;

//*** private LSP heap ****
HANDLE gLspHeap = NULL;

int LspCreateHeap( int *lpErrno    )
{
    gLspHeap = HeapCreate( 0, 128000, 0 );
    if ( NULL == gLspHeap )
    {
        *lpErrno = WSAEPROVIDERFAILEDINIT;
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }
    return NO_ERROR;
}

void * LspAlloc(    SIZE_T  size,    int    *lpErrno    )
{
    void *mem = NULL;
    mem = HeapAlloc( 
            gLspHeap, 
            HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, 
            size
            );
    if ( NULL == mem )
    {
        *lpErrno = WSAENOBUFS;
    }

    return mem;
}

void LspFree(    LPVOID  buf    )
{
    HeapFree( gLspHeap, 0, buf );
}

//**********************************************

LPWSAPROTOCOL_INFOW EnumerateProviders(
    WINSOCK_CATALOG Catalog, 
    LPINT           TotalProtocols
    )
{
    LPWSAPROTOCOL_INFOW ProtocolInfo = NULL;
    DWORD               ProtocolInfoSize = 0;
    INT                 ErrorCode = NO_ERROR,
                        rc;

    if ( NULL == TotalProtocols )
        goto cleanup;

    *TotalProtocols = 0;

#ifdef _WIN64
    // Find out how many entries we need to enumerate
    if ( LspCatalog64Only == Catalog )
    {
        // Find the size of the buffer
        rc = WSCEnumProtocols( NULL, ProtocolInfo, &ProtocolInfoSize, &ErrorCode );
        if ( SOCKET_ERROR == rc )
        {
            if ( WSAENOBUFS != ErrorCode )
                goto cleanup;
            ErrorCode = NO_ERROR;
        }

        // Allocate the buffer
        ProtocolInfo = (LPWSAPROTOCOL_INFOW) LspAlloc(
                ProtocolInfoSize,
               &ErrorCode
                );
        if (ProtocolInfo == NULL)
            goto cleanup;

        // Enumerate the catalog for real
        rc = WSCEnumProtocols( NULL, ProtocolInfo, &ProtocolInfoSize, &ErrorCode );
        if ( SOCKET_ERROR == rc )
            goto cleanup;

        // Update the count
        *TotalProtocols = rc;
    }
    else if ( LspCatalog32Only == Catalog )
    {
        HMODULE            hModule;
        LPWSCENUMPROTOCOLS fnWscEnumProtocols32 = NULL;

        // Load ws2_32.dll
        hModule = LoadLibrary( TEXT( "ws2_32.dll" ) );
        if ( NULL == hModule )
            goto cleanup;

        // Find the 32-bit catalog enumerator
        fnWscEnumProtocols32 = (LPWSCENUMPROTOCOLS) GetProcAddress(
                hModule, 
                "WSCEnumProtocols32" 
                );
        if ( NULL == fnWscEnumProtocols32 )
            goto cleanup;

        // Find the required buffer size
        rc = fnWscEnumProtocols32(NULL, ProtocolInfo, &ProtocolInfoSize, &ErrorCode);
        if ( SOCKET_ERROR == rc )
        {
            if ( WSAENOBUFS != ErrorCode )
                goto cleanup;
            ErrorCode = NO_ERROR;
        }

        // Allocate the buffer
        ProtocolInfo = (LPWSAPROTOCOL_INFOW) LspAlloc(
                ProtocolInfoSize,
               &ErrorCode
                );
        if ( NULL == ProtocolInfo )
            goto cleanup;

        // Enumrate the catalog for real this time
        rc = fnWscEnumProtocols32( NULL, ProtocolInfo, &ProtocolInfoSize, &ErrorCode );
        if ( SOCKET_ERROR == rc )
            goto cleanup;

        // Update the count 
        *TotalProtocols = rc;

        FreeLibrary( hModule );
    }
#else
    if ( LspCatalog32Only == Catalog )
    {
        // Find the size of the buffer
        rc = WSCEnumProtocols( NULL, ProtocolInfo, &ProtocolInfoSize, &ErrorCode );
        if ( SOCKET_ERROR == rc )
        {
            if ( WSAENOBUFS != ErrorCode )
                goto cleanup;
            ErrorCode = NO_ERROR;
        }

        // Allocate the buffer
        ProtocolInfo = (LPWSAPROTOCOL_INFOW) LspAlloc(
                ProtocolInfoSize,
               &ErrorCode
                );
        if ( NULL == ProtocolInfo )
            goto cleanup;

        // Enumerate the catalog for real
        rc = WSCEnumProtocols( NULL, ProtocolInfo, &ProtocolInfoSize, &ErrorCode );
        if ( SOCKET_ERROR == rc )
            goto cleanup;

        // Update the count
        *TotalProtocols = rc;
    }
    else if ( LspCatalog64Only == Catalog )
    {
        puts( "Unable to enumerate 64-bit Winsock catalog from 32-bit process!");
    }
#endif
    else
    {
        // Find the size of the buffer
        rc = WSCEnumProtocols( NULL, ProtocolInfo, &ProtocolInfoSize, &ErrorCode );
        if ( SOCKET_ERROR == rc )
        {
            if ( WSAENOBUFS != ErrorCode )
                goto cleanup;
            ErrorCode = NO_ERROR;
        }

        // Allocate the buffer
        ProtocolInfo = (LPWSAPROTOCOL_INFOW) LspAlloc(
                ProtocolInfoSize,
               &ErrorCode
                );
        if ( NULL == ProtocolInfo )
            goto cleanup;

        // Enumerate the catalog for real
        rc = WSCEnumProtocols( NULL, ProtocolInfo, &ProtocolInfoSize, &ErrorCode );
        if ( SOCKET_ERROR == rc )
            goto cleanup;

        // Update the count
        *TotalProtocols = rc;
    }

cleanup:

    if ( ( NO_ERROR != ErrorCode ) && ( NULL != ProtocolInfo ) )
    {
        LspFree( ProtocolInfo );
        ProtocolInfo = NULL;
    }

    return ProtocolInfo;
}

void PrintProtocolInfo( WSAPROTOCOL_INFOW *wsapi)
{
    WCHAR       szGuidString[MAX_PATH],
                wszProviderPath[MAX_PATH];
    INT         dwProviderPathLen=MAX_PATH-1;
    int         rc, error, i;

    rc = WSCGetProviderPath(
           &wsapi->ProviderId,
            wszProviderPath,
           &dwProviderPathLen,
           &error
            );
    if ( 0 != rc )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "WSCGetProviderPath failed: %d\n", error);
        lstrcpyW(wszProviderPath, L"(error)");
    }

    //
    // Display protocol information
    //

    printf("*** %S ***\n", wsapi->szProtocol);
    printf("Path: %S\n", wszProviderPath);      

    //
    // Display provider ID and catalog ID as well as LSP chain information
    //

    StringFromGUID2( wsapi->ProviderId, szGuidString, MAX_PATH-1 );

    printf("Provider Id: %S\n", szGuidString);

    if(wsapi->ProtocolChain.ChainLen == LAYERED_PROTOCOL)printf("LSP: Yes\n");
    else printf("LSP: No\n");

    printf("Catalog Entry Id: %ld\n", wsapi->dwCatalogEntryId);
    printf("Number of Chain Entries: %d   {",wsapi->ProtocolChain.ChainLen);

    for(i=0; i < wsapi->ProtocolChain.ChainLen ;i++)
        printf("%ld ", wsapi->ProtocolChain.ChainEntries[i]);

    printf("}\n");    

    printf("Version: %d\n\n", wsapi->iVersion);    
}



void FreeProviders( LPWSAPROTOCOL_INFOW ProtocolInfo )
{
    LspFree( ProtocolInfo );
}




void PrintProviders( WINSOCK_CATALOG Catalog)
{
    WSAPROTOCOL_INFOW  *pProtocolInfo = NULL;
    INT                 iProtocolCount = 0,
                        i;

    // Enumerate catalog and print it
    pProtocolInfo = EnumerateProviders( Catalog, &iProtocolCount );
    if ( NULL == pProtocolInfo )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "PrintProviders: Unable to enumerate catalog!\n" );
        goto cleanup;
    }


    for(i=0; i < iProtocolCount ;i++)
    {       
       PrintProtocolInfo( &pProtocolInfo[ i ] );            
    }

cleanup:

    if ( NULL != pProtocolInfo )
        FreeProviders( pProtocolInfo );

    return;
}

int main(void)
{
#ifdef _WIN64
    WINSOCK_CATALOG     eCatalog        = /*LspCatalog64Only*/LspCatalogBoth;
#else
    WINSOCK_CATALOG     eCatalog        = LspCatalog32Only;
#endif  

    WSADATA  wsd;
    int rc;

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");    
    // Load Winsock
    rc = WSAStartup( MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsd );
    if ( 0 != rc )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Unable to load Winsock: %d\n", rc );
        return -1;
    }

    // Initialize data structures
    LspCreateHeap( &rc );

    // Print the 32-bit catalog
    if ( ( LspCatalogBoth == eCatalog ) || ( LspCatalog32Only == eCatalog ) )
    {
            printf( "\n32-bit providers:\n\n" );            
            PrintProviders( LspCatalog32Only);
            printf( "=======================\n" );
    }
    // Print the 64-bit catalog
    if ( ( LspCatalogBoth == eCatalog ) || ( LspCatalog64Only == eCatalog ) )
    {
            printf( "\n64-bit providers:\n\n" );            
            PrintProviders( LspCatalog64Only);
            printf( "=======================\n" );

    }       

    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```